# Поиск противоположной пары в массиве PHP

Tags: php

Проверить, есть ли в одномерном числовом массиве хотя бы одна пара противоположных чисел. Помогите пожалуйста

Comment: Что вы уже пробовали?

Comment: А что такое "противоположные числа"?

Comment: @MBo, числа, отличающиеся знаками. Напр., `5` и `-5`, то есть те, @Ярослав, которые в сумме дают `0` ;)

Comment: я не могу понять какой алгоритм поиска должен быть для такого(

Comment: @Ярослав, подсказку я уже дал комментарием выше. Хотя, вы можете подождать и кто-нибудь обязательно сделает эту простейшую операцию вместо вас.

Comment: @Deonis не заметил подсказку

Comment: Отсортировать по модулю, далее использовать подсказку от @Deonis. Можно не сортировать, но тогда будет немного сложнее.

Answer (score 2):

Можно использовать побитовый оператор `~` *(NOT)* в комплекте с функциями поиска in_array() и фильтрации array_filter():

```
$numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, -7, 8, 9, -9];

$arr = array_filter($numbers, function($int)use($numbers){
    return in_array(~--$int, $numbers);
});

var_dump($arr);
```

В результате будет получена пара чисел `9` и `-9` *(для остальных пары нет)*

Comment: глючит на `[PHP_INT_MIN, PHP_INT_MAX]`

Comment: @rjhdby что бы вы посоветовали?

Comment: можно добавить проверку на PHP_INT_MIN с возвратом false. Но я бы сделал просто вложенный цикл `for(i=0;i<length-1;i++){for(j=i+1;j<length;j++){if($a+$b===0){`

Answer (score 1):

Ладно, я сделаю это за вас

```
$arr = [2, 4, 5, -3, -4];
foreach ($arr as $item) {
  if ($item && in_array(0 - $item, $arr) {
    die("Есть!");
  }
}
echo "Нет.";
```